# How to speed up batch watershed delineation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, algorithm, hydrology

I have a large number of pour points - approximately 250,000 for which I want to delineate the upstream watershed area using ArcHydro's "Batch Watershed Delineation". Given that it takes roughly 4-5 hours for 1000 points to delineate on my system I need to find a faster way than just running these as individual processes on my computer. Currently I am testing out running 4 sets of 1000 side-by-side on my 64bit windows i7 system, so that will likely speed up the process, but I think it could be sped up even more through an opportunity to access a "condor" type system which runs multiple applications of a program at any given time.

The catch is that I need to talk to ArcGIS from a command line and also get ArcHydro to work from command line to do the upstream watershed delineation. I know the files that I require, so would likely just need to know if it is possible to extract the code that ArcHydro uses to define the entire upstream catchment area of points. I can't seem to find that easily within the ArcGIS GUI.

Would anyone know of a way to identify/extract the code that ArcHydro is using to run "Batch Watershed Delineation", and if so would you also know how to call to ArcGIS to do that process without opening ArcGIS and running it from a command line?

Comment: It's unlikely you will be able to produce a useful map from 250,000 (overlapping?) areas.  This suggests you will be post-processing them for summary statistics such as their areas, mean slopes, or whatever.  Perhaps there are more efficient algorithms that exploit spatial relationships among the pour points to obtain these final results.  If you could describe the nature of your pour points and the ultimate objective of this analysis, you might get replies that are far more effective than merely speeding up the current procedure.

Comment: I need to know the watershed areas for the points, its actually less than 250,000, I did some cleaning and its around 200,000. The points are intersections of two line intersections, and I need the watershed area of each point. Some of these points are close to each other, but they are all unique and we would like to determine the watershed area for each point. We will use the watershed area in a predictive model to distinguish a score for each point. I hope this is a more useful description.

Comment: Run a `FlowAccumulation` calculation using a constant grid as input.  (Set its values to the area of a single cell).  Then simply read off its values at each of the 200,000 points.  Fast and easy.

Comment: I am not sure I get how this tells you the entire upstream area draining to the point. I tried running flow accumulation on a constant grid (with a value of 8100 as that is my grid cell area (90x90 cells)) and it returned a value of 0. Perhaps I need to predefine the boundaries? I am doing this for multiple watersheds, not just one. I also should have been more clear that I am interested in the total are draining to the point not just the immediate watershed area.

Comment: "Total area draining to the point" is (obviously) equivalent to "total number of cells draining to the point" times "area of a cell."  The former is *precisely* what FlowAccumulation calculates.  It sounds like you need to work a little harder on getting FA to work correctly.  Remember, it takes two inputs: one for the amount of water per cell and another to indicate the flow directions.  The output will look like a network of streams; it cannot possibly be all zero when it's run correctly.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense now that you explained it that way, your initial explanation of just creating a flow accumulation layer based on a constant raster did not make sense, as I had input that raster into ArcHydro. Clearly the way is to use the default Flow Accumulation in ArcGis. Cheers that worked fine! I very much appreciate your suggestion, it saves me a LOT of time.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know it worked.  For the record, I will digest these comments into a formal answer.

Answer (score 5):

In a conversation following the question, we refined the objective.   It is to obtain

> the watershed area of each point. Some of these points are close to each other, but they are all unique and we would like to determine the watershed area for each point. We will use the watershed area in a predictive model to distinguish a score for each point.

The proposed solution, which worked in this case (and was *far* faster than the batch watershed delineation), is to run a FlowAccumulation calculation using a constant grid as input. (Set its values to the area of a single cell). Then simply read off its values at each of the 200,000 points.

To understand this, note that the total area draining to a point is (obviously) equivalent to "total number of cells draining to the point" times "area of a cell." The former is precisely what FlowAccumulation calculates when it is given a unit grid as input.

An important insight here is that sometimes (frequently, in my experience) we can accomplish a compute-intensive task more efficiently by focusing on our ultimate objective, rather than on each specific technical step in a workflow, and attempting to identify an accurate and fast algorithm to reach that objective.  Adding more processors, getting speedier disks, etc., can speed up a long operation, but only by a limited amount.  Changing the algorithm altogether can improve it by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick point about getting the value of each point from the flow accumulation matrix. if the points (junctions) had been extracted from vector streams, probably these points do not match the corresponding points in the DEM. So, the points should first snap to the right place based on the DEM.  There is a tool in ArcGIS named Snap Pour Point for doing this.